# Swift: How to Return to Earlier Function After didFailWithError

Tags: swift, xcode6, core-location

I was wondering if I could get some advice on how to have an app recover and start working again after an error, or how to avoid the error in the first place. I have a code that prints "Success" if the App is close enough to a certain coordinate, and "Not close enough" if not within the area. This seems to work fine. However, when I simulate an area that's too far away, then switch to an area in range, then back to an area that's out of range, I encounter an error and it stops updating the location. So it prints "Success", then "Not close enough", then "Error: downThe operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)". This also happens if I start from an area that's in range and switch to an area that's out of range - for some reason it's fine if it starts out of range and moves into range but not the opposite.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil)
    {
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

        if placemarks.count > 0{
        let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
        self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        self.playSound(pm)
    }
        else {
            println("Error with the data.")
        }

    })


}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
{
    println(placemark.locality)
    println(placemark.postalCode)
    println(placemark.administrativeArea)
    println(placemark.country)
    println(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude)
    println(locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!){
    println("Error: down" + error.localizedDescription)
    return
}

func playSound(placemark: CLPlacemark)
{
    if locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude > 44.638832 && locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude < 44.638834 {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        println("success")
    }
    else {
        println("Not close enough")
        return
    }
}

}
```

It's this error function that's giving me trouble:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!){
    println("Error: down" + error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
```

I'm quite new to Swift, so hopefully this is just a simple case of having functions in the wrong order or not including some basic syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I think I solved it. Took "return" out of the last else statement, and now after 10 seconds it recovers from the error and starts showing location updates again.

Comment: so what;s the error ? you are getting

Comment: It's "Error: downThe operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)" Not totally sure why it happens, but I seem to have gotten the code to resume after the error.